# Make PHP code run on .net?

Tags: php, .net

I can write PHP application in linux platform.
However, I getting a request to explore the idea to run PHP application into .NET.

I have zero .NET knowledge.
So wondering, is it possible?

Is it advisable? Implication ? Or maybe I should just install a .NET to playaround first?

In short, zero code changes, except setup the PHP environment in .net.

Also, wondering, will this benefits from .net security?

The reason why I explore this idea is because Singapore government website must run on  .NET (and I intend to save few bucks by not hiring dot net developers). I think the idea of application must run on .NET is absurd (a joke to me), just showing one of the "world-class" standard in Singapore :)

Comment: I'm confused as to your question.  Are you trying to run a php application on a .net (Windows) platform? Yes you can do that.  Or are you trying to migrate your application to a .Net environment, e.g. Asp.net in which case you'd have to rewrite it and then you would "have" to run it on a Windows platform.

Comment: i mean to make the php code run on .net

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You can run PHP on Windows, on an IIS server (or Apache, or anything else), but you can't turn PHP into .NET code without rewriting it.

Comment: @Stephen Orr: yes, you can.

Comment: @Klee: you also seem to be confused about .Net. It's a platform quite separate from the Windows OS.

Answer (score 5):

So basically, what you want is to compile PHP to CIL, the bytecode language of .NET. This is in fact possible using [Phalanger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_%28compiler%29).

I have no experience using it, but I wouldn't expect existing PHP applications to run on it without problems, especially considering that most PHP apps rely heavily on extensions which are themselves not written in PHP. But that's an obvious problem, maybe the people working on Phalanger have come up with solutions.

Comment: oh, you have a point on the extensions

Comment: ...you can run a number of applications/CMSs on it. Like Wordpress. [With GOOD benchmarks too](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Mar-05.html). (I would be worried about scalability, thought)

Comment: (fact is: php base functionality is large, and phalanger reimplements it, -or at least tries to- php non-standard binary extensions are rare and hard to keep current, while most custom setups/functionality is done trough the shell)

Comment: @ZJR - Scalability should be pretty good as PHP is interpreted whereas CIL is much closer to machine code.

Comment: @JamesSnell I was thinking more on the lines of "what to do when you have to throw more hardware in and add some replication". It certainly can be done, but the LAMP way differs so much from the MS Stack way, you might encounter issues with the company sysadmins along the way. (and yes most people won't run into this sort of trouble)

Comment: @ZJR - I can't see it being an issue especially since the clients mandate .Net, they'll have the means to scale apps without a problem.  I can predict some interesting conversations when something goes wrong, but that's a management issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "run PHP application into .NET"...

a) You can run PHP sites in the server technology that .Net websites run on, its called IIS.  This is just like running your PHP under Apache so there are no changes to your application.  However, you are not really gaining anything from this as its just running the PHP application the same as Apache and the only reason people would do this is if their hosting solution is already using IIS.

b) If you mean you want to convert your PHP to a .Net application, I would suggest that you learn how ASP.Net works and port it across manually rather than using an automated tool.  PHP and ASP.Net are very different beasts so they work in different ways.  Besides, if you are expected to maintain the application in .Net then you will need to know how it works.

Comment: They don't necessarily need to use MVC however, your answer makes out this is the only option.

Comment: Good point, I have taken the MVC part out.  It seems that since I have moved from WebForms to MVC that I have become unknowingly biased to MVC!

Comment: .NET isn't just ASP. It's has a runtime that interprets CIL bytecode, and Phalanger doesn't translate PHP source code, it compiles to CIL just like Aspnet_compiler.exe does. You could maintain the PHP code just fine, except it would run in the .NET platform instead of the Zend engine. But of course that's just the PHP code, the extension library would pose problems, as would integration into the .NET server architecture.